# type issue with n choose k in haskell

Tags: haskell

I defined this in Haskell

```
import Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Binomial 
hello i j p n = [(n `choose` l)*(p^l)*((1-p)^(n-l)) | l <- [i,i+1..j]]
```

It compiles but when I try to run 'hello' with a non integer p, ghci says:

```
No instance for (Fractional b0) arising from the literal `0.75'
The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
In the third argument of `hello', namely `0.75'
In the expression: hello 2 5 0.75 10
In an equation for `it': it = hello 2 5 0.75 10
```

Seems like it is a type issue but I am unable to resolve it. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Adding an explicit type signature to `hello` will clarify things a lot!

Comment: I tried that, but without succes. Could you please indicate me how to do that correctly?

Comment: What do you *want* the type of `hello` to be? What are `i`, `j`, `p`, `n` and the return value? Think of an explicit case first (i.e. concrete types), and then we can think about typeclasses later. From your code I want to suggest (as a first version) that `i`, `j`  and `n` are `Integer`s and `p` is a `Double`.

Comment: i,j and n should be integers, and p any Num. I tried (Num t) => Integer -> Integer -> t -> Integer -> [t] and it does not work.

Comment: Right, let's say `p :: Double` do be concrete for now. Now `n choose l` must be `Integer` (check the signature of `choose`), and `p^l` is the same type as `p` , namley `Double` (check the signature of `(^)`). Thus you are trying to apply `(*)` to an `Integer` and a `Double`. This you cannot do. How about you pass the first argument of `(*)` through `fromIntegral`?

Comment: oh, that clarifies the problem

Comment: thanks gspr, it works!

Answer (score 1):

It's a type issue deeper than can be solved:

```
λ> :t hello
hello :: Integral b => b -> b -> b -> b -> [b]
```

Your `hello` function only works on integrals.  This is inherited from the `choose` function, which also only works on integrals:

```
λ> :t choose
choose :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with Double o Floating? p is supposed to be a quantile of a distribution

Comment: @monalisa well, if you know what you're doing, there's nothing preventing you from lifting the `choose` code (or rewriting it altogether from other sources) so that its types fit what you want. It would be kind of weird to still name it "choose", though.

Answer (score 0):

As @JB. pointed out, if you ask ghc (or ghci) for the type of `hello` it responds with:

```
hello :: Integral b => b -> b -> b -> b -> [b]
```

which says that `p` must be an integral value.

There is a further problem, though. Suppose `p` is a Double and the rest or the arguments are `Int` values. Then we have the following types:

- `choose n l` is an `Int`
- `p ^ l` is a `Double`
- `(1-p) ^ (n-l)` is a `Double`

and we are trying to multiple them all together. In Haskell you can't multiply an `Int` and a `Doulble` without converting one to the other's type. The way in Haskell to generically convert a integral value is to use `fromIntegral`, so you want to use:

```
(fromIntegral (choose n l)) * (p^l) * ((1-p) ^ (n-l))
```